# Auto synchronize saving of custom block editor entities

Tags: block-editor

I added a custom entity to block editor, it serves a purpose to save some data to custom-made table in database:

```
dispatch('core').addEntities([{
    label: 'kalendar',
    name: 'events_meta',
    kind: 'extra_table/v1',
    key: 'id',
    baseURL: 'extra_table/v1/events_meta',
    baseURLParams: { context: 'edit' },
    plural: 'events_metas'
}]);
```

It is edited inside post, with custom block. Is there a way to automatically save this entity edits when user saves a post? Currently, editor asks a question which entities to save (one being a post itself and other this entity) and shows checkmarks. I would like to avoid this.

**Edit:**
I attach image of options which appear when saving:
[image]

Editing entity (inside block event callback onChange):

saving for the first time:
`saveEntityRecord('extra_table/v1', 'events_meta', { post_ID: curPostID, startDate: prop.startDate }).then(record => { set_events_meta_ID(record.id); setAttributes({events_meta_ID: record.id}) });`

editing afterwards:
`editEntityRecord('extra_table/v1', 'events_meta', attributes.events_meta_ID, {startDate: prop.startDate});`

Comment: Is this code complete? Can you share an image of the checkbox UI you're referring to?

Comment: Code for adding entity is complete. However, code for manipulating entity is not attached, I will add it also, it is pretty standard. This is not a new issue, when I added nested editor (editing another post inside post), since it is also a new entity, this options also appear.

Comment: it is this editing afterwards (editEntityRecord) which leave editor state dirty and cause prompting for saving. However, I do not want to use `saveEditedEntityRecord` immediately after, for performance reasons.